# how to read a value from excel table stored in memory c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the value of a cell from an Excel spreadsheet.  The value is stored in sheet1, cell A2, which is under a column heading called Item.  The code below always returns the value as null.  Please help me get the value stored in A2.

```
using Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Test
 {
     public class ExcelUtil
     {
         public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string fileName)
         {
             FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
             IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream); //.xlsx
                        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
              DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
              DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
              DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];

              return resultTable;
        }

        public static List<Datacollection> dataCol = new List<Datacollection>();

         public static void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
         {
             DataTable table = ExcelToDataTable(fileName);
             //Iterate through all the rows and columns of the Table
             for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
             {
                 for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
                 {
                     Datacollection dtTable = new Datacollection()
                     {
                         rowNumber = row,
                         colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                         colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
                      };
                      //Add all the details for each row
                      dataCol.Add(dtTable);
                   }
               }
           }

       public static string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
       {
           try
           {
                //Retrieving Data using LINQ
                string data = (from colData in dataCol
                                           where colData.colName == columnName && colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                                           select colData.colValue).SingleOrDefault();

                //var data = dataCol.Where(x => x.colName == columnName && x.rowNumber == rowNumber).SingleOrDefault().colValue;
                            return data.ToString();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               e.Message.ToString();
               return null;
            }
        }

        private static void mytest()
        {
            string itemNo = ExcelUtil.ReadData(1, "Item");
         }
    }

public class Datacollection
{
    public int rowNumber { get; set; }
    public string colName { get; set; }
    public string colValue { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Which method returns null? Did you try debugging the code and see why it returns null? How should I run this code on my machine? Which method should I call?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya You need to save an excel worksheet locally on your PC with a couple of rows, the first row will have the heading and you can put anything in the second row. Yes I tried debugging, but I get the same error. : resultTable error CS0103: The name 'resultTable' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I forgot to add that I also have the file name  to my initialize class as well:          ExcelUtil.PopulateInCollection(@"Data.xlsx");  The application fails to get the string of itemno field (which is A2 from the excel spreadsheet)

Comment: Does your code compile? You first said it returns null. Are you getting this error at runtime or compile time? Which line shows the error?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes it does compile.  But the value returned is null.

Comment: What do you get in  `e.Message.ToString();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! I needed to add the following 2 rows to my code above:

```
            private static void mytest()
            {
                ExcelUtil util = new ExcelUtil();
                ExcelUtil.PopulateInCollection(@"c:\datalocation\Data.xlsx");

                string itemNo = ExcelUtil.ReadData(1, "Item");
            }
```

and I had to modify the following as well:

```
                    public static string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
            {
                try
                {
                    ////Retrieving Data using LINQ
                    var data = (from colData in dataCol
                                where colData.colName == columnName && colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                                select colData.colValue).First().ToString();

                    //var data = dataCol.Where(x => x.colName == columnName && x.rowNumber == rowNumber).SingleOrDefault().colValue;
                    return data;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.Message.ToString();
                    return null;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

That code will help you a lot in that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
namespace EXEL_DB
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OleDbConnection coon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=""C:\A.xls""; Extended properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""");

    OleDbCommand com;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter da;
    public Form1()
    {

        coon.Open();
        fillgrilll("");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new System.Data.DataView(dt);

        dv.RowFilter = "group by [langue com] order by [langue com]";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }

    void fillgrilll(string re)
    {
        try
        {
            dt.Clear();
               // My sheet i name it A but you have to write [A$]
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [A$] where datepart(month,[Shipment Date]) = datepart(month,'06/04/2016')", coon);
            da.Fill(dt);
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch {
            MessageBox.Show("Errr");
        }
    }
}
}
```

`